# what is flexigrid?

Tags: .net, flexigrid

in .net we use something called datagrid and there is what we call flexigrid .
what is the difference in between ?

Answer (score 2):

[Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/)

> Lightweight but rich data grid with
>   resizable columns and a scrolling data
>   to match the headers, plus an ability
>   to connect to an xml based data source
>   using Ajax to load the content.

Features

```
* Resizable columns
* Resizable height and width
* Sortable column headers
* Cool theme
* Can convert an ordinary table
* Ability to connect to an ajax data source (XML and JSON[new])
* Paging
* Show/hide columns
* Toolbar (new)
* Search (new)
* Accessible API
* Many more
```

Comment: The documentation on this jQuery plugin is lacking, heavily

Comment: There is NO documentation whatsoever. The only way I could get documentation was to read source code.

Answer (score 0):

FlexiGrid is generated on the client (using JavaScript) and the ASP.NET GridView/DataGrid is generated on the server. The FlexiGrid also has a number of features as described by @phoenix

Answer (score 0):

Both controls, flexigrid and datagrid, are ment to present data to the user of your web application.

Major difference between them is that the datagrid, in order to go to the next page, makes a full request for the page.
Flexigrid, on the other hand, gets only the next page of data, not the entire page.

There's also some client-side "goodies" with flexigrid, like showing/hiding columns, resizing columns and such.

If you're looking for a ASP.NET implementation of flexigrid, have a look at http://www.flexigrid-asp.net